# Joomla 2.5 - How to open specific menu item in lightbox?

Tags: joomla2.5, lightbox, joomla-content-editor

I am developing a site using Joomla 2.5 and the JCE editor with the Mediabox plugin installed and enabled.

I am trying to have 3 of my menu items open in a lightbox. For each of the menu
items, I went to **Link Type Options** and under **Link CSS Style**, I have added the `jcepopup noicon`.

When I save the items and refresh the front end of the site (even going so far as
clearing my cache), the `jcepopup` and `noicon` classes are not applied to any of those three menu items.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the menu module that you are using. Just because the parameters exists in the menu item does not mean that the menu module uses them. You will probably need to create a template override for the menu module that includes the classes in the links.

Comment: I am not using a menu module. Just Joomla's default menu system.